# OR search in solr

Tags: solr

I have a situation where I have to search a document in Solr with multiple OR keywords. Now the number of keywords may lead up to 5000 which is resulting in a awfully large query with 5000 OR conditions. This is resulting in the Solr server to hang. Is there any other way I can design the query to work. Short sample of the query is given below

tweet_id:337931022601699328 OR 337931064293081089 OR 337931089538584576 OR 337931098761871361 OR 337931138851016704 OR 337931143099854848 OR 337931160082591745 OR 337931163857453056 OR 337931230819516416 OR 337931239996665857 OR 337931287518126080 OR 337931322850951168 OR 337931325648535553 OR 337931331398934528 OR 337931413057830912 OR 337931442363441152 OR 337931448629731329 OR 337931453344129025 OR 337931465016877056 OR 337931482066726912 OR 337931514388029442 OR 337931533149155328 OR 337931645527130114 OR 337931704935256064 OR 337931784459268096 OR 337931845545103360 OR 337931889086185472 OR 337931892668108801 OR 337931963983855617 OR 337932154212319233 OR 337932176454721536 OR 337932193198374912 OR 337932229659459584 OR 337932437290090496 OR 337932436807749632 OR 337932436828725250 OR 337932437449474048 OR 337932448518250496 OR 337932458832035843 OR 337932458634915840 OR 337932458278387712 OR 337932474246119425 OR 337932476209041409 OR 337932477408620544 OR 337932480478842880 OR 337932478775959554 OR 337932480566931456 OR 337932478763376640 OR 337932481841999872 OR 337932479337992192 OR 337932479296045057 OR 337932479333797889 OR 337932484614434816 OR 337932484606038017 OR 337932482777317376 OR 337932484664758272 OR 337932482785718273 OR 337932484589273088 OR 337932487399444481 OR 337932489031032833 OR 337932489114923008 OR 337932486573166592 OR 337932490704560130 OR 337932489144270848 OR 337932488762601472 OR 337932492097069056 OR 337932497780355072 OR 337932498900230144 OR 337932499722321921 OR 337932514431729665 OR 337932561806409731 OR 337932567284154368 OR 337932567300935680 OR 337932574603214848 OR 337932571134533632 OR 337932574674518016 OR 337932575484026881 OR 337932578206121984 OR 337932582215892994 OR 337932586653454336 OR 337932584917024768 OR 337932592986865664 OR 337932597017587712 ....

I intend to facet the result based on a few fields.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to feed Solr with that amount of IDs? If you give us your use case, we could probably provide a better way to solve it. Since feeding solr with loads of IDs is not its' sweetspot.

Comment: I agree with @cheffe, if all these tweets belong to a specific user, then query by user_id, if they belong to the same hashtag, then lookup the hashtag. Anyway, provide more information to clarify your use-case so we can help you better.

Comment: My use case is that I have a list of tweet ids. Now I want a faceted result of some fields from the tweets which have those tweet ids. The approach I am following is that I am preparing a query by ORing the tweet ids in a faceted query. Now the list of tweet ids may rise to almost 10k which is resulting in an awfully large query which solr is not able to handle. A solution to the problem or any alternate solution to the use case is welcomed.

Comment: @mjalajel The tweets neither belong to the same user nor to the same hashtags. The tweet list we get from some analysis of the tweets. There is no common relationship among the tweets through which it can be searched.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this solution would help you or not, but tried something for your problem.

Whatever the query you provide to Solr, first it parses that query to it's understandable format. Then Solr executes that for result. **You have to do some calculations before querying to Solr**. Let's take the following scenario to solve your use case.

Suppose You have total 5000 **tweet_id**. You have to do an **OR** query on around 4000 tweet_id. In this type of scenario, it's better to query on other (5000-4000=1000) 1000 tweet_id with  negation **AND** query. So, your query will have less values passed.

So, try querying with rest of the tweet_id with negation AND query instead of OR query.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create a new field denoting this `custom_list_id` .. Whenever you generate a new list, index the new data then query by the list I'd.